# Looping through Inputs in Elixir or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, elixir

I'm new to elixir so forgive me for asking this basic question.

I have modal which has option to add both email and number fields. The emails or number are then put in an array. I'll will be using the emails to send info through the inputted email address. Same thing goes with the mobile number. What I want to do is to send emails through my controller one at a time until all emails are used. Is there is a way to do a loop in elixir or maybe in jQuery?

Comment: Take a look at [`Enum.each/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#each/2).

Answer (score 1):

There are dozillions of ways to loop through lists in Elixir. [`Enum.each/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#each/2), [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1), [`Stream.resource/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Stream.html#resource/3), plain old good [recursion](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/recursion.html), etc.

I would suggest you to start with reading [Elixir Official Guide](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/enumerables-and-streams.html) before trying to build a complicated web application.